# Javascript failing in Firefox/Firebug?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firebug

I'm using Firebug to develop a JS app. All of a sudden, when I got to the page, it appears that I do not have JS enabled - the `<noscript>` warnings are rendered, and nothing works. When I go to the same page in Chrome, everything works fine.

What could be happening? I reverted recent changes back to a point where it worked, but it's still failing.

**UPDATE**: I just went back to the page in question, and now it works fine. I had been working on it in Chrome. Odd.

Comment: Do you get any errors in Firebug's Console or Net tabs?  If you try disabling Firebug and loading your page w/o it enabled what do you get?  Tried un-installing / reinstalling Firebug?

Comment: No errors in the Console or Net tabs. Disabling Firebug has no effect. I haven't tried reinstalling it yet.

Comment: Is it possible that you flipped your browser into "Disable Javascript" mode?  I have the "Preferences Toolbar" extension installed, and every once in a while I accidentally switch off the "Enable Javascript" checkbox ...

Comment: @Pointy no, I am still in "Enable Javascript" mode.

Comment: Well, I use Firebug on a daily basis, and I have for years, and while it does have all sorts of irritating issues I've never seen it shut down Javascript completely.  Are you using the same browser on Stackoverflow?  Does the Javascript here work?

Comment: Yes, SO works fine in the same browser. The case in which it fails is a localhost Django devserver.

Comment: It seems more likely to me that Javascript is wonky because you're doing something locally, and not due to firebug. Of course, the latter is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I've had to disable Firebug entirely. Way too many errors and bung-eyes there.

Worked wonders for a long time, but recently... not so.

I've switched to Chrome + Developer extension - which does fall short, but it does the trick.